# How to get status of custom resource using Kubernetes C# .net Client?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

I have created an `Elasticsearch` resource using the below yaml manifest after installing the eck-operator as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html).

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.15.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

After this manifest is applied, I can get the status manually by executing:

```
kubectl get elasticsearch -n ecknamespace
```

and the output would be as follows:

```
> $ kubectl get elasticsearch -n ecknamespace
  NAME          HEALTH   NODES  VERSION   PHASE   AGE 
  quickstart    green    3       7.15.0   Ready   3d17h
```

Using the [Kubernetes C# Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp), how do I get the above data programmatically?

Comment: is this related to java?

Comment: the APIs of java and C# k8s client are similar, so the implementation would be similar

Comment: if you add the java tag, then java developers will see this post and probably be a bit cranky that the question is not about java. tags should be precise, it's not an exercise of adding as many as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client includes an [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/examples/customResource) of how to interact with custom resources.

It will require you to define the classes described in the files `cResource.cs` and `CustomResourceDefinition.cs`.

Afterwards, the following code should list the `elasticsearch` resource:

```
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();
var client = new GenericClient(config,  "elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co", "v1", "elasticsearches");
var elasticSearches = await client.ListNamespacedAsync<CustomResourceList<CResource>>("default").ConfigureAwait(false);
foreach (var es in elasticSearches.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(es.Metadata.Name);
}
```

**EDIT** after OP's comments: to view all fields of the custom resource, one needs to edit the `CustomResource` class (file `CustomResourceDefinition.cs` in the example) with the corresponding fields.

Comment: I tried that - however i am not getting the "HEALTH", "PHASE" and other fields shown in the output of kubectl get elasticsearch

Comment: In the future, please describe your previous attempts and their results in the question. Also, can you please add to your original question the output of `kubectl get elasticsearch -n ecknamespace -o json`? This way I can edit my answer to include the fields.

Comment: I got it, I stepped into the function ListNamespacedAsync and see those fields coming in the response JSON. Those fields go missing during deserialization due to my customresource class structure.